# fetching 1 line up and 1 line down from a line number

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to display few lines from a file. What I know is something like this:

```
head -n48964204 xag
```

But this will display the line number as mentioned. what I am trying is to fetch the record for line number `48964203,48964204,and 48964205.`

I have also tried this: `sed -n 48964204p xag`  but this displays only one single line of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `sed` you specify the first line and last line you want like this

```
sed -n '48964203,48964205p' xag
```

since you know the line number specify the previous number and the subsequent number!

#### Explanation

- `-n` be quiet until we ask you to **p**rint something
- `2,7` the first line I want and the last line I want & everything in between. This is an address.
- `p` print those lines

Comment: I learned a little bit of `sed` using the [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html) you suggest, it was fun, however I can't really remember what I read :D

Comment: @Ravexina there's one on `awk` on that site too and I can never get past the introduction :S

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==48964203,NR==48964205' xag
```

It will return lines 48964203 to 48964205 and includes both of them.
Using `NR` we can specify the input records so `awk` only prints specified lines for us.

Answer (score 1):

Perl approach:

```
perl -lne 'print if $.>=48964203 and $.<=48964205' input.txt
```

The  key idea is to print line numbers that correspond to logic expression - line number is greater or equal to 48964203, and line number is less than or equal to 48964205.